# Windows Batch: passing environment variable that contains newlines as parameters

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am currently running into issue with such setup:

Received environment variables (in pseudocode syntax):

```
PIPELINE_ID = 12345
COMMIT_SHA = 123456abcdef
COMMIT_MESSAGE = "This is a message that
contains
newlines"
```

The variables are passed from GitLab runner into Windows Batch, in Bash they work perfectly.

The issue happens here:

```
call process_release --notes "%PIPELINE_ID% %COMMIT_SHA% %COMMIT_MESSAGE%" > release.log
```

The effect is that `PIPELINE_ID` and `COMMIT_SHA` are passed correctly but the rest causes this:

```
'This' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'contains' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'newlines' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

And the `release.log` file is not created.